# Was Guru Nanak an avatar of Janak raja?

Tags: ramayana, janaka, sikhism

Was Guru Nanak an avatar of Janak raja, father of Maa Sita of Ramayana and Bramha gyani?

Comment: As far as i know there is no such reference in any of the puranas/itihasa regarding Guru Nanak Ji being an avatar of Raja Janak.

Comment: what is the source of your Qn/where did you read this??

Comment: @Rāmachandra I do not remember properly the source, but I am pretty sure I have heard/read it somewhere. As far as I remember, Janak raja wanted to teach others about the reality and hence he needed to come 9 times as Sikh gurus (all Sikh gurus not only Guru Nanak Ji).

Answer (score 2):

No,

King Janak got moksha(freedom from cycle of birth and death)

> Bhagavad Gita 3.19
>
> Therefore, giving up attachment, perform actions as a matter of duty
> because by working without being attached to the fruits, one attains
> the Supreme.
>
> Bhagavad Gita 3.20 – 3.21
>
> By performing their prescribed duties, King Janak and others attained
> perfection. You should also perform your duties to set an example for
> the good of the world. Whatever actions great persons perform, common
> people follow. Whatever standards they set, all the world pursues